# When merging can I mark all changes in a file as if those changes were merge conflicts

Tags: git

I just received [a rather large pull request](https://github.com/peter1000/subuser/commit/0f2d4993ff215d566f40e29b7b7e7aa42f2048a6) and I would like to go through the commit line by line, changing things as I go(I don't like some of the coding practices used).  It seems to me that it would be nice to be able to process each change as if it were a merge conflict.   Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could do an interactive rebase and stop at each commit for editing.
I would suggest doing your changes on top of the to-be-merged branch as fixup commits
`git commit --fixup=123456abcdef`
to the relevant commits and then do a
`git rebase -i master_branch --autosquash`
which will put all fixups to the right place.